# Using Batch Files and ffprobe what is the best approach for finding 5 videos with lowest preset?

Tags: windows, ffprobe

I am on Windows 10 Pro.

I am trying to find an effcient logic or way using a batch file, to search for videos in a folder.

And give me 5 file names w/paths that have the lowest bitrate or video preset.

Then once I have that will convert those five to a higher preset.

This is the current logic of my batch file.

Loop thru all the video file extensions

Loop thru all files in subfolders with that file extension

ffprobe to get the bitrate and push that to a temporary text file

end both loops

then parse temporary text file to show video files w/paths that have the lowest bitrate/video preset.

Is there logic that would speed up this process?

OR better usage of ffprobe or an alternative tool?

Thank you for your thoughts.